# HtmlFormDocument is no longer a child of “element” in my html page

Tags: javascript, server, windows-server-2003

I just changed the server of my App. In the previous version “element” had the two following child nodes:

1. “forms”, which is a HtmlCollection and contained the childNode “Form1”
2. The HtmlFormElement “ Form1”
   So if I wanted to access “Form1” from JS, the syntax “element.Form1” was acceptable.

Now I upgraded the server, and “Form1” is no longer a direct child of “element”. It means that the only way I can access “Form1” is with the syntax “element.forms[“Form1”]”.

It screwed all my JS function. I tried to change the CustomHeader in the IIS to the Explorer 6, but without success.

the upgrade was made from server 2003 to server 2012, maybe i need to use server role of "iis 6 management compatibility"?

Comment: I don't get it. What exactly is your question.

Comment: In short: in the previous server in the JS function "element.Form1" returned the HtmlFormElement "Form1". Now it returns null. Only the syntax “element.forms[“Form1”]” returns this value. How can I rollback? What can I do so that "element.Form1" returns me the correct value?